# WebResponse Timeout Error in C#

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am trying to send image using web service. I am converting image first to base64 string and using web request Post method sending to server. Here is my code.

```
try
{
    qry = "Select ProductImage From tbl_Product where ProductOnlineID=0";
    dt = db.DataTable(qry);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        string fileName = dr["ProductImage"].ToString();
        string storeLocation = Application.StartupPath + @"\product_image\";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(storeLocation + fileName))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile(storeLocation + fileName);
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            string url_upload_imag = @"http://Myserver/api/offline/json/1.0/index.php";
            string rq = "token=" + apikey + @"&json_data={%22method%22:%22uploadProductImagesLocal%22,%22data%22:[{%22imgName%22:%22" + fileName + "%22,%22imgString%22:%22" + base64String + "%22}]}";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url_upload_imag);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = rq.Length;
            byte[] array = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(rq);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            using (Stream str = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                str.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
                using (WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject_Image));
                    RootObject_Image obj = (RootObject_Image)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(ws.GetResponseStream());
                    MessageBox.Show("Done" + fileName + obj.data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error in Sending Image:" + ex.ToString(), "Error:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

My Problem is..When I run the application I get Time out Error..I've tried everything setting timeout to infinite doesn't work for me. My base64 string is also correct.

Web service is created in php. what could be error?? and if there is any error, from which side it could be, PHP or C#?

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting your code when you post. Most of your code was indented way more than it needed to be.

Comment: Have you used Wireshark or something similar to work out whether you're managing to send the request, and it's just not being processed quickly enough?

Comment: @Jon Skeet- No I didn't try Wireshark. I tried APIKITCHEN and it is working good.

Comment: Do you have any logging on the server side. Can you see your web server handling the request? Have you tried running you server side code in a test harness, passing in the same values as you are posting from your client code?

Comment: @Nattrass: Unfortunately we are not having any credential to look in server side. it is not developed by us. that's why I am asking that error is from which side? it is important to me to know this first..

Comment: @Arvaan: Ok, when you said that API Kitchen worked, do you mean that the client received the POST and processed the message successfully, ie, no timeout? You could use fiddler to check the actual message that is being posted to the server side from your C# code and compare this to the message being sent by API Kitchen.